# Web api always return the server responded with a status of 405

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

Developed a project with Angularjs, web api and implemented custom storage Identity.

Before implementing asp.net identity, calling methods worked well.

After implemented identity, when I call post method using angularjs, web api always returns, "the server responded with a status of 405".

I don't know the reason. Here I mentioned the step by step flow how I am implemented web api.

```
OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {

                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
                //,
                //Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
                //RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
            };


            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/api/Common/LogIn"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {   //error on the line below
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, Guid>(
                            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                            (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                            (identity) => Guid.Parse(identity.GetUserId()))
                }
            });
```

when I call thorough angluarjs like

```
$http.post('/api/Common/LogIn', loginData).success(function (response) {

            localStorageService.set('authorizationData',
            { token: response.access_token, userName: response.userName });

            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = response.userName;

            deferred.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (err, status) {
            _logOut();
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
```

Web api actually redirect to `"http://localhost:4082/api/Common/LogIn?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FCommon%2FLogIn"`.

Then I've implemented Provider for serveroauthoptions like following.

```
 public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        ApplicationUserManager UserManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
        PasswordVerificationResult result = PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            result = UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.Password, context.Password);

            if (!(result == PasswordVerificationResult.Success))
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        context.Validated(identity);
    }
```

After implemented provider, when i call sigin post method throught angularjs, I always got "Unauthorized error" or sometime I got "Calling method doesn't support get method" with the link `"http://localhost:4082/api/Common/LogIn?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FCommon%2FLogIn"`.

Actually I don't what is the mistake I've done. Can anyone please tell me the solution for this ?

Do I need to include more information to this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen an answer to this somewhere already, but can't find it, so here goes (in the Startup.Auth.cs file in App_Start):

```
    public void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app) {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
                OnApplyRedirect = ctx => {
                    if (!IsApiRequest(ctx.Request)) {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static Boolean IsApiRequest(IOwinRequest request) {
        String apiPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/api/");
        return request.Uri.LocalPath.StartsWith(apiPath);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @steen. I've implemented as per your suggestion. But Now I got error like "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Comment: Note, I didn't include [Authorize] attribute for "/api/Common/LogIn" Login action...

Comment: Thanks a lot for all.. But I found the bug. I need to include [AllowAnonymous] tage before the method. I thought by default It'll accept the method.

Comment: @Jeeva, by default it should work without AllowAnonymous unless you have a "filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());" registered in your RegisterGlobalFilters method of FilterConfig getting called from Global.asax (which is not a bad idea).